# MYSQL search database for similar results

Tags: php, mysql

Essentially what I want to do is search a number of MYSQL databases and return results where a certain field is more than 50% similar to another record in the databases.

What am I trying to achieve?
I have a number of writers who add content to a network of websites that I own, I need a tool that will tell me if any of the pages they have written are too similar to any of the pages currently published on the network. This could run on post/update or as a cron... either way would work for me.

I've tried making something with php, drawing the records from the database and using the  function similar_text(), which gives a % difference between two strings - this however is not a workable solution as you have to compare every entry against every other entry & I worked out with microtime that it would take around 80 hours to completely search all of the entries!

Wondering if it's even possible!?

Thanks!

Comment: -1 for acceoting your own answer based on the answers of others ... crappy thing to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers guys, for anyone looking for a solution to a problem similar to this I used the `SOUNDEX` function to pull out entries that had a similar title then compared them with the `similar_text()` function. Not quite a complete database comparison, but near as I could get it!

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for is SOUNDEX. It is the only sound based search in mysql. If you have A LOT of data to compare, you're probably going to need to pregenerate the soundex and compare the soundex columns or use it live like this:

```
SELECT * FROM data AS t1 LEFT JOIN data AS t2 ON SOUNDEX(t1.fieldtoanalyse) = SOUNDEX(t2.fieldtoanalyse)
```

Note that you can also use the

```
t1.fieldtoanalyze SOUNDS LIKE t2.fieldtoanalyze
```

syntax.

Finaly, you can save the SOUNDEX to a column, just create a column and:

```
UPDATE data SET fieldsoundex = SOUNDEX(fieldtoanalyze)
```

and then compare live with pregenerated values

**More on Soundex**

Soundex is a function that analyzes the composition of a word but in a very crude way. It is very useful for comparisons of "Color" vs "Colour" and "Armor" vs "Armour" but can also sometimes dish out weird results with long words because the SOUNDEX of a word is a letter + a 3 number code. There is just so much you can do sadly with these combinations.

Note that there is no levenstein or metaphone implementation in mysql... not yet, but probably, levenstein would have been the best for your case.

Answer (score 2):

*Anything is possible.*

Without knowing your criteria for *similar*, it's difficult to offer a specific solution. However, my suggestion would be pre-build a similarity table, utilize a function such as `similar_text()`. Use this as your index table when searching by *term*.

You'll take an initial hit to build such an index. However, you can manage it easier as new records are added.

Comment: Hi Jason,
It's difficult to define the criteria for similar, maybe if I explain why I want to find similar records that will help you understand what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a number of writers who add content to a network of websites that I own, and I need a tool that will tell me if any of the pages they have written are too similar to any of the pages currently published on the network.

Comment: Similarity table sounds intriguing, how would I go about doing that?
Cheers

Comment: I'd suggest updating your post or even asking that question separate. But as far as the MySQL table is concerned, in index table as I've described is the way to go.

Comment: something like stackoverflow do, when you try to post some question that is similar to another, there are a warning! Try to compare TITLES only, not content. If your network is big, it will slow down a bit everytime one User has posted something ..